# Selection Sort in Java produces incorrect results

Tags: java, selection-sort

I am new to Java and I am trying to write a selection sort program.
Below is my code :

```
public class SelectionSort {
    public static int a[] = {6, 4, 9, 3, 1, 7};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min, i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            min = i ;
            for(j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j] < a[min]) {
                    min = j; 
                }
                if (min != i) {
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[min];
                    a[min] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("a : " + a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My input array is `6,4,9,3,1,7`. The sorted output should be `1,3,4,6,7,9`
But the output I am getting is:

```
a : 3
a : 4
a : 6
a : 7
a : 1
a : 9
```

I am doing some small mistake which I am unable to figure out. Can anyone please help me fix it?

Comment: +1. You provided short code, an input, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are almost there.

**The part that swaps elements should be *outside* the inner loop.**

In other words, you need to *first find* the smallest element in the remainder of the array, and *then swap* it into the current position. Right now you're swapping as soon as you have found a smaller number, and in the process failing to keep track of the new position of this smaller number.

Another way to fix the code is to keep the swap where it is, but update `min` after each swap:

```
if (min !=i) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[min];
    a[min]= temp;
    min = i;       /* Update `min' to reflect the number's new position */
}
```

This too will work, but is rather inefficient.

P.S. The `if (min != i)` check is unnecessary since swapping an element with itself is a harmless no-op.

Answer (score 6):

You are swapping the elements for each iteration of inner loop  Put the below block outside the inner loop. You should swap only for each iteration of *outer loop*.

```
         if (min !=i) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[min];
                a[min]= temp;
            }
```

Comment: Oh yes I got it now . But what will happen if the swap code is in the inner loop?

Comment: @Newbie -  you are swapping each time your `(min !=i)` condition is true. You will end up swapping a value which is *already swapped*, i.e, your array will actually be *out-of-order* (with respect to the expected output of each iteration) in the iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Why cant you go with comparator in collection. As you are new to java, you can learn the feature provided by java too. Check the below example for that.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyIntComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return (o1>o2 ? -1 : (o1==o2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------------
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Simple2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(5);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(1);
        Collections.sort(list, new MyIntComparable());
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though, does it?

Comment: Its the answer to change the approach. :)

Comment: Your class is a *comparator* not a *comparable*, so name it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple logic to approach any algo is to break into multiple step :
    
### Step 1 − Set MIN to location 0 or any high Value
    ### Step 2 − Search the minimum element in the list
    ### Step 3 − Swap with value at index of minimum
    ### Step 4 − Repeat until iteration gets over
e.g. <br>
14, 33, 27, 10, 35, 19, 42, 44 <br>
**10**, 33, 27, **14**, 35, 19, 42, 44 <br>
10, **14**, 27, **33**, 35, 19, 42, 44 <br>
10, 14, **19**, 33, 35, **27**, 42, 44 <br> 
10, 14, 19, **27**, 35, **33**, 42, 44 <br>
10, 14, 19, 27, **33**, **35**, 42, 44 <br>
10, 14, 19, 27, 33, 35, **42**, 44 skip as no min found

    
    
        final int[] intArr = new int[]{14, 33, 27, 10, 35, 19, 42, 44};
        int index = -1;
        boolean isMin;
        for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
          int min = 999999999;
          isMin = false;
          for (int j = i + 1; j < intArr.length; j++) {
            if (intArr[j] < min && intArr[i] >= intArr[j]) {
              min = intArr[j];
              index = j;
              isMin = true;
            }
          }
          if (isMin) {
            intArr[index] = intArr[i];
            intArr[i] = min;
          }
        }
        Arrays.stream(intArr).forEach(System.out::println);
```