# Selection sort on my array list of objects not working JAVA

Tags: java, selection-sort

I'm having trouble with my sorting algorithm, it sorts the first two cards but then messes up. The Array list is an attribute of the deck, so I have to access it with methods in the deck class such as get card and get deck. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                                       
    minVal = deck.getCard(i).getVal();                              
        for (int j = i ; j < 5 ; j++ ) {

            if (deck.getCard(j).getVal() < minVal)                  
            {

                minVal = deck.getCard(j).getVal();                  

                for (int k = i ; k < 5 ; k++) {
                    if (deck.getCard(k).getVal() == minVal)         
                    { 

                        buffer = deck.getCard(i);                   
                        deck.set(i, deck.getCard(k));               
                        deck.set(i + 1, buffer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my output:

```
Original Cards:    
3
2
14
8
6
Updated cards:
2   
3
6
6
8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selection Sort in Java produces incorrect results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279412/selection-sort-in-java-produces-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

```
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < getCard(i).length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1 ; j < getCard(i).length() ; j++ ) {
        if (deck.getCard(j-1).getVal() < deck.getCard(j).getVal()) {
            temp = deck.getCard(j-1).getVal();
            deck.getCard(j-1).getVal() = deck.getCard(j).getVal();
            deck.getCard(j).getVal() = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there's no swap in iteration at least break it. Also it would be nice to provide some comments rather than throwing bunch of code without explanation.

Comment: Maybe explain your answer instead of just dumping the code? That way the OP (and others) could actually learn from it...